# hacer un ciclo que me permita asignar un nro y que comience desde 1 por cada nro de orden en php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo muchos registros que se ingresan con un mismo nro de referencia, ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer un ciclo para que la columna item comience desde 1 y así sucesivamente hasta que el numero de referencia sea otro.

Allí en el ejemplo tengo 3 items por el nro de referencia 5231 entonces el item debería de comenzar por 1 luego 2 y 3 y si después de eso sigue otro numero de referencia que vuelva a empezar en 1.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Referencia</td>
    <td>Item</td>
    <td>Numero</td>
  </tr>

<?PHP

$sql=mysql_query("select * from pedidos,proform_llant,detalle_fac,precios where pedidos.fecha_pedi between '$fecha_md' and '$fecha_md1'
and pedidos.proform_nro=proform_llant.rfq_no 
and proform_llant.id_prof=detalle_fac.fk_factura
and detalle_fac.fk_producto=precios.id_pre order by pedidos.pedido_nro, precios.tamano_one DESC, precios.tamano_two DESC");
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){        

    $id=$res["id"];
    $referencia=$res["referencia"];
    $numero=$res["numero"];


?>  
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $referencia; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $numero; ?></td>
 </tr> 
  <?php
}
  ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola, ¿sigues necesitando ayuda con este problema?

Comment: Asi es, no he logrado solucionar.

Comment: Vale, ya te di mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente comprueba si es igual que el anterior y listo (debe llegar ordenado por referencia)

```
$ultima = '';
$contador = 1;
```

.... Código que va al bucle

```
if($ulitma == $referencia){
        $contador++;
}else{
      $contador = 1;
}
```

Comment: Hola @Manuel Robles ese if comienzo colocandolo en donde esta la variable item cierto?

Comment: Básicamente, la otra respuesta que te dieron es la explicación de lo que te puse yo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Manuel Robles.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos a centrarnos en la parte donde escribes tu `while` y los datos:

```
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){        

    $id=$res["id"];
    $referencia=$res["referencia"];
    $numero=$res["numero"];


?>  
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $referencia; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $numero; ?></td>
 </tr> 
  <?php
}
```

Yo lo que haría sería usar una variable auxiliar, cuando ésta cambie de valor, entonces la cuenta regresa a 1. Ejemplo:

```
//inicializamos el contador en 1
$contador = 1;
//inicializamos a un string vacío la variable auxiliar
$aux_referencia = "";
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){        

    $id=$res["id"];
    $referencia=$res["referencia"];
    $numero=$res["numero"];
    // Punto 1        
    if ( $referencia != $aux_referencia ) {
       $aux_referencia = $referencia;
       $contador = 1;
    }
    // Punto 2
    else {
       $contador++;
    }

?>  
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $referencia; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $contador; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $numero; ?></td>
 </tr> 
  <?php
}
```

Aquí explico los puntos comentados en el código:

1. Aquí la primera vuelta del `while` entra y se cumple porque $referencia sí es diferente de `""`  (valor de $aux_referencia inicial) y por lo tanto el $contador es igual a 1
2. Si `$referencia` es igual a `$aux_referencia` el contador va a seguir aumentando de 1 en 1 hasta que éstas sean diferentes y se cumpla el `if` principal en cada vuelta para que el valor de $contador regrese a 1.

Al final obtendrías el resultado que esperas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que esta lógica te sirva y puedas implementar la modificación. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Fernando Torres, excelente solución muchas gracias por la ayuda, muy agradecido.

Comment: Siempre es un gusto, qué bueno que te funcionó, saludos!